# MVP examples for Windows Forms 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

Is there good example code or a test project for explaining the [Model–view–presenter (MVP) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). There are a lot of explanation links, but I want to have some good example code to show others without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Jeremy Miller's "Build your own CAB" series is fantastic.  You get a nice dose of MVP (along with some other smart client patterns such as Pub/Sub).

http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx

Comment: I found [buildyourowncab](https://code.google.com/p/buildyourowncab/) at code.google.com. It looks like the sourcecode to the article Build your own CAB by jeremy miller.

Comment: The series link is dead as of April 2017 but I found a copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20160928041924/http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [Claymore](http://claymore.codeplex.com/) Framework.