# Is MVC# Popular with Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

Is this a popular combination out there ([MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/) and Winform)? Is MVC really worth it with traditional Winform application development? Or should I just stick with the 3tier model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVP (Model-View-Presenter) and MVP-VM (Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel) is used most often with WinForms.

See SO question:

[Winforms - MVP examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185993/winforms-mvp-examples)

Dan Bunea's Blog Post: [Model View Presenter](http://danbunea.blogspot.com/2005/11/model-view-presenter-is-testing_27.html)

Jeremy D. Miller's Blog Post: [A Simple Example of the "Humble Dialog Box"](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/articles/129546.aspx)

Michael Feathers: [The Humble Dialog Box](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: where can I view some samples?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this framework
http://koosserymvcwin.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=koossery.MVCwin%20Overview&referringTitle=Home